# Different sizeof(long) values in W7 and Linux Mint

Tags: c, windows, long-integer, sizeof, linux-mint

IDE: Code::Blocks 13.12

Compiler: GNU GCC

Application type: console application

Language: C

Platforms: W7 and Linux Mint

I wrote a compiler and interpreter for a self defined language, I made executables for Windows and Linux. The compiler - obviously - generates a code file that is read by the interpreter. I want to use the compiled file both on Windows and Linux. So, a file created with the Windows compiler must be readable by the Linux interpreter and vice versa.

I can't get the compatibility to work. I found that in Windows, the sizeof(long)=4 and in Linux, sizeof(long)=8. As the compiler will write long integers to the output file I think the difference in size is (part of) the problems I have.

I checked this forum, but similar problems are mostly about casting and writing platform independent C++ code. I also found some suggestions about using (u)intptr_t but these are also pointer related.

Maybe the quickest solution is to use type int rather than long in Linux, but then I would have different sourcecode for both platforms.

Is there another way to handle this issue?

Comment: Can('t) you use the fixed-width variables?

Comment: @Marnix: This is a problem with any binary format. You have to decide what data format to use, no matter the internal representation on the system you happen to compile on. Also, it's not just lengths, but also things like byte order, so if you want your compiled file to work on other architectures it's not enough just to use uint64_t.

Comment: You apparently serialise datatypes by simple casting. That is the very wrong way. Use proper serialisation with shift/masking and fixed-width types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `int32_t` for a 32 bit 2's complement signed integral type, and `int64_t` for a 64 bit 2's complement signed integral type.

Note that a compiler doesn't have to support these types, but if it does then they must be as I describe.

An `int` in C can be as small as -32767 to +32767. A `long` must be at least 32 bit. MSVC maintains a `long` as 32 bit on 64 bit systems (it uses the LLP64 model). The C standard does not place an upper limit on the sizes. This flexibility allows optimal C compilation on a variety of platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a specific size used a type with the size suffix in it like **uint64_t**.The size of a **long** integer varies between architectures and operating systems.
Reference Link:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models