# C: LONG_MIN and LONG_MAX are wrong

Tags: c, long-integer

Running Windows 64 bit system. Values appear as if they are just int.

```
int main()
{
    long long_min = LONG_MIN;
    long long_max = LONG_MAX;

    printf("Minimum value of long: %ld \n", long_min);
    printf("Maximim value of long: %ld \n", long_max);
    printf("Printing the size of long: %zu\n", sizeof(long_max));

    printf("\n----------------------------------\n\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEQCc.png)

Ran my program in a online compiler and it worked how it was supposed to. Showing that long is:

```
Minimum value of long: -9223372036854775808 
Maximim value of long: 9223372036854775807 
Printing the size of long: 8
```

Comment: On Windows long and int are the same width. On other platforms like Linux and Mac they are different width. Both are correct.

Comment: What's wrong with them?

Comment: More info: [Why is the size of a native long primitive on 64-bit Windows only 4 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446588/why-is-the-size-of-a-native-long-primitive-on-64-bit-windows-only-4-bytes) [Different sizeof(long) values in W7 and Linux Mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719889/different-sizeoflong-values-in-w7-and-linux-mint)

Comment: Use `std::int64_t` or `std::int_least64_t` if you want at least 64 bit integers.

Comment: One 32 bit Linux, `long` is likely 32 bit too. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/eoT69sYMG)

Comment: Aside: use `%zu` format for `sizeof`.

Comment: I do hope you also don't have any other similar expectations, such as "pointers are really just `long` (or `int`) values" or "`size_t` is really just `unsigned long`".  Those misbeliefs are unfortunately all too common and they **will** bite you.

Comment: @RetiredNinja "On Windows ... " and "On other platforms like Linux and Mac ..." incorrectly assumes that it is an OS concern.  It is more likely a compiler choice.  On my Widows machine `LONG_MAX` is 9223372036854775807, 64-bit.

Comment: In MSVC `long` is 32-bits in both the 32-bit and the 64-bit compilers. IMO there is never a need to use `long` except when an interface requires it. Avoid.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The definitions of sizes for data types **is** an OS concern, because it's the OS that provides the interfaces that use those sizes.  [Microsoft's `LONG_MAX` for Windows is defined to be `2147483647`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/integer-limits?view=msvc-170).  Note that these are [**Windows Data Types**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types):  "`LONG` A 32-bit signed integer. The range is -2147483648 through 2147483647 decimal.

This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:

`typedef long LONG;`"

Comment: When a Windows OS interface specifies `long`, it's specifying a 32-bit value, not a 64-bit one.  The compiler that compiles source code to use that interface isn't relevant.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `LONG` may be 32-bit in `WinNT.h` (and that is a compiler file, not an OS one.  Yet `long` is 64-bit when I compile and it does do not use `WinNT.h`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Try passing the address of a [`LARGE_INTEGER` union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-large_integer-r1) based on that definition of `long` to [`GetFileSizeEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesizeex) and say the size of `long` on Windows is 64 bits...  The OS expects 32 bits where there are supposed to be `long` values in that union, not 64 bits.  If you have a compiler that makes that call with a 64-bit "long", that compiler is flat-out wrong.

Comment: @AndrewHenle,  To get the file size, [many approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/238603/2410359) are possible other than `GetFileSizeEx()` using a compiler on a windows machine.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica If you **really** believe `long` is 64 bits on Windows, then you'll edit [the Wikipedia page for 64-bit computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) that currently lists Windows as having an LLP64 data model **with 32-bit `long` values** and change Windows so that it falls under the LP64 model with 64-bit `long` values.  That edit will be visible to everyone.  You'll also file a bug report with Microsoft about their incorrect documentation.  If you fail to do both of those, you don't even believe in yourself.

Comment: @AndrewHenle When I compile a C program, my `long` are 64-bit.  I am not writing the OS - which is a large set of code. Compilers used for those programs, libraries, etc., can have `long` as 32-bit. And programs I write can have `long` as something else.  Any difference between the two is handled by my compiler & its library. Likewise OP's code, after adding _standard_ headers, compiles on my windows machine and reports "Minimum value of long: -9223372036854775808 Maximim value of long: 9223372036854775807 Printing the size of long: 8". The range of a `long` is determined by compiler, not OS.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Notice the [linked data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) has "Microsoft Windows (x86-64 and IA-64) **using Visual C++; and MinGW**", listing 2 _compilers_.  Same table has using other compilers, one can have LP64, on windows such as, "...  **Windows when using Cygwin; z/OS**", where `long` is 64-bit.  The wiki already supports the idea that `long` size is dependent on more than just the OS.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica So edit the Wiki page.  Or you don't even believe yourself.  And tell us how calling `GetFileSizeEx()` with a `LARGE_INTEGER` structure based in 64-bit `long` values works instead of tap dancing.  You've done neither of those.  And file that bug report with Microsoft for incorrect [documentation on **Windows Data Types**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) that lists `long` as 32-bits.  Until you do those things, you're just trolling with al lie.

Comment: Possible later edits to comments were missed: The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) already supports the idea that `long` size is dependent on more than just the OS.  Do you think the <one can have LP64, on windows such as, "... Windows when using Cygwin; z/OS"> is amiss?  If so then you can edit the wiki or reports its error.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Good luck using [Windows user-mode scheduling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-ums_system_thread_information) with your 64-bit `long` values on Windows.  `typedef struct _UMS_SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION {
  ULONG UmsVersion; ...`  N.B. the many `long` and `unsigned long` values in that Windows scheduling structure.  Have fun interfacing with the Windows kernel using 64-bit `long` values where the kernel expects 32-bit `long` values.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Routines like `GetFileSizeEx()`  and those of Windows user-mode scheduling, are designed to work with various Visual C like compilers.  Other compilers provide their own libraries to perform their select functionality and use their own kernel and/or handle interfacing to a windows one.  Thus user of other compilers do not need to have the fun  suggested.

Answer (score 2):

C standard only defines **minimum** sizes of those types 5.2.4.2.1

| LONG_MIN | LONG_MAX |
| --- | --- |
| -2147483648 | +2147483647 |

So both compilers are correct.

Comment: Please do not post snips in answers. This content can be easily reproduced in an accessible format.

Comment: Note that C23 differs for the minimum value of `LONG_MIN`: it shall be `-2147483648`, and must be written as `(-2147483647-1)` or an equivalent expression to ensure `LONG_MIN` has the proper type.